# Grammatical name for a "which means …" clause that elaborates on a verb

Tags: grammar, terminology

Consider a sentence like the one below.

> Radioactive materials *decay*, which means that their atomic nuclei lose energy by emitting particles.

What grammatical classification and name would you assign the “which means […] particles” clause? It is a bit like a nonrestrictive appositive in that it elaborates on *decay*, but *decay* is a verb and the structure is a bit different.

Comment: The construction is a relative clause, non-restrictive, but the antecedent of the relative pronoun _which_ is the entire previous clause.

Comment: @KarlG Thanks. Are you suggesting that the relative clause shouldn't be interpreted as a definition of *decay*, but an elaboration on the entire thing? If it matters, the original text italicizes *decay*, (I'll fix the question).

Comment: I'm not sure it makes a difference, since the decay is specific to radioactive materials rather than, say, that tub of yogurt that got pushed to the back of the fridge and forgotten. With _which_, one would ordinarily look for a noun  antecedent, but there's only _materials_, and the clause describes the decay (n.) of radioactive materials, so in essence, the whole independent clause.

Comment: The clause is a supplementary (non-defining) relative, an additional unit of information. Supplementary relative clauses do not modify anything, but refer to a semantic 'anchor', which can be virtually any preceding element. In this case the anchor is the entire preceding clause "Radioactive materials decay"

Comment: Thanks both of you, you've provided a very useful starting point for further study (I haven't studied grammar properly for many years). @KarlG I have one more clarifying question if you'll indulge me; I think I'm close to properly understanding the dynamics at play here. Would your analysis change with respect to the antecedent if the sentence named a specific material? E.g., "Uranium *decays*, which means its atomic nuclei lose …."

Comment: No, it would still be the whole clause supplemented by the relative, at least according to BillJ (with different terminology) and me, but LuneKrltksr wants to anchor it more specifically to the verb.

Comment: Thanks again @KarlG and BillJ for your enlightening comments. This doesn't seem to be a particularly popular question, but it might be helpful if one of you two were to resubmit your comment(s) as an answer since you two disagree in part with LuneKeltkar and his is currently the only answer (even though it builds on your comments). I'm not prepared quite yet to declare that I'd accept your answer since more answers may come and there is some disagreement, but so far your responses were the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the dependent clause is relative, but it clearly anchors to *decay*, not the entire independent clause.  The relative clause defines *decay*.  Restated:  "Radioactive materials *decay*, which [term] means that their atomic nuclei lose energy by emitting particles."